# How to prevent Oracle from converting dates to number during table creation?

Tags: sql, oracle, dbeaver

I am trying to execute a CREATE TABLE command in Oracle SQL but when I specify DATE as the column format, the resultant dtype is NUMBER. Similarly when I try to create table with a provided row, it still returns the result as a number. How can I force it to create a blank date column?

```sql
CREATE
TABLE MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE
AS
    SELECT
        'Day' AS agg_level,
        SYSDATE AS agg_date
    FROM dual;
```

Comment: Cannot replicate your problem [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/OHeXsSYO) - the table is created with `CHAR` and `DATE` columns, there are no `NUMBER` columns.

Comment: What does _blank_ mean? All null values?

Comment: I also used the below and got the same result of agg_date being a number. I noticed that this does not happen when creating the table in another schema that I own. Perhaps there is some setting to change?

CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (
    agg_level VARCHAR2(255),
    agg_date DATE
);
INSERT INTO MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (agg_level, agg_date)
VALUES ('Day', TO_DATE('2024-01-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd'));

Comment: Are you sure you're querying/checking `MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE`, not some other table in another schema? Also where does the python tag fit in - are you doing this directly in an Oracle client, or through python, or something else?

Comment: Yes. I first discovered this issue using oracledb and thought maybe there's some issue with python data types. But I've since reproduced the issue entirely via my sql query editor itself (DBeaver) using SYSDATE to ensure that I am trying to create a date

Comment: It seems unlikely, but could you possibly have [an `instead of create` trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-7B32FE4B-AB8E-48B0-A74C-599584A485A7) on that schema?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I force it to create a blank date column?

If you want it to create a table with zero rows then you do not need to use `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` and could, instead, explicitly specify the columns and data-types:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE(
  agg_level CHAR(3),
  agg_date  DATE
);
```

or, using `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` add a filter that is always false to get a table with zero rows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (agg_level, agg_date) AS
  SELECT 'Day', SYSDATE
  FROM   DUAL
  WHERE  1 = 0;
```

If you want to create a single row with a `NULL` value using `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` then use `CAST(NULL AS DATE)`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE (agg_level, agg_date) AS
  SELECT 'Day', CAST(NULL AS DATE)
  FROM   DUAL;
```

If you want to check what the data-type of the column is then use:

```sql
SELECT owner, table_name, column_name, data_type
FROM   ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE  owner = 'MY_SCHEMA'
AND    table_name = 'MY_TABLE'
```

It should list all the columns and their data-types and you should see that `AGG_DATE` has the `DATE` data-type. If that is the case and you see numbers when you read the data then the problem is either:

1. You are reading from a different database, schema, and/or table and not from the `MY_SCHEMA.MY_TABLE` in that database instance you just created the table in (because you won't get numbers back from a `DATE` column); or
2. There is a problem with the code you are using to read from the database and you are performing a conversion somewhere from a date to a number (you have tagged `python-oracledb` but not shared any python code and we cannot help with code we cannot see).

Comment: This was what I initially did. However, the resultant agg_date column format is NUMBER. That's why I thought of creating it with one dummy row to see if it coerces the type to be a date but still to no avail.

Comment: @fluent If you do `SELECT owner, table_name, column_name, data_type FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE owner = 'MY_SCHEMA' AND table_name = 'MY_TABLE'` what does it tell you that the data-types are? If it is `DATE` then the problem is not in Oracle but somewhere in Python when you are reading the data and it is converting Oracle's dates to a number in Python.

Comment: I will have to double check that later, but I'm pretty sure it showed DATE. Also, I have been testing this directly via DBeaver to avoid potential python dtype conversion issues, and still the same result.